# How to display photo and url shorten on my tweet

Tags: facebook, twitter, meta-tags, meta

I have synchronized my Facebook to my Twitter page so whenever i post a link on my Facebook page it display the photo and the name well check below image:
[image]

but on my tweet page it will only show the link with no name and i will have to click view photo to see photo check below image:

the meta tag on the page where i share the link

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="photo" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@Eventc" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="<?php echo ucwords($data['event_title']); ?>" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://eventciti.com.ng/<?php echo $data['event_image']; ?>" />
<meta name="twitter:url" content="http://eventciti.com.ng/event/<?php echo $data['event_title']; ?>" />
```

so how do i display the photo in my tweet and also shorten the url?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

To display the image in a tweet, you have to create a tweet with an image added **manually** to display it. Sadly meta tags do not achieve what you want.

If you want to use an api, I do not know an php API.
You can use twitter4j with the following lines to display an Image automatically or search for an php alternative or call twitter directly.
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update

```
StatusUpdate update = new StatusUpdate("Message and http://Link");
update.setMedia(new File("pictureto show"));
twitter.updateStatus(update);
```

I think the url is automatically visually truncated if it is too long and at the end of the message.